# Protected Git Submodule Heroku

Tags: git, github, heroku

I am trying to push commits from git to Heroku. My project has a private submodule which is causing the following errors during deployment:

```
remote: Git submodules detected, installing:
remote: Submodule 'surveyScriptContents' (https://github.com/PurplePineapple123/Post-Purchase-Survey-Script-Tag.git) registered for path 'surveyScriptContents'
remote: Cloning into 'surveyScriptContents'...
remote: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
remote: fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/PurplePineapple123/Post-Purchase-Survey-Script-Tag.git' into submodule path 'surveyScriptContents' failed
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected, submodule install failed
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/morning-peak-19860.git
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/morning-peak-19860.git'
```

Reading the [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-submodules#protected-git-submodules) it looks like I just need to change the URL in my `.gitconfig/.gitmodules` file to follow this structure: `https://username:password@github.com/myusername/FooBar`.

However, Heroku adds this warning: `Since submodule references are stored in plaintext in the .git/submodules directory please consider if this is acceptable for your particular security requirements.`

I've been looking for ways to properly authenticate the submodule without exposing my password. However, I'm struggling to figure out how to make this work. I've explored using an .env variable but that did not work.

Any idea how properly authenticate a private submodule to allow pushes to Heroku?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://www.sectorlabs.ro/blog/2017/4/21/heroku-and-git-submodules

Comment: I have the same problem, I tried to use a TOKEN from GitHub instead of username:password but it does not work, any idea?

Comment: @Merlyn007 Try using a deploy key in your ```.gitmodules``` file. It URL reference should be formatted like. The first part being the deploy key: https://2D1o5401zpaXqsDkOA9MI4eRanl@github.com/your_github_account/Submodule_repo_name.git

Comment: Now it works fine, thanks for your answer @InquisitiveTom

I had configured the submodule as SSH instead of HTTPS that's why it failed, now I got it sorted with the TOKEN.